# Index lists of lists using forloop.counter in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have list of lists like the following one :

altcrit = [ [something1,something2] , [somethingelse1,somethingelse2] ,,,, ]

I pass the list as context in my template .

My template follows :

```
<form method='POST'>
{% csrf_token %}
{{ criterion_value_formset.management_form }} 
{% for form in criterion_value_formset %}
    {% with index=forloop.counter0 %}
    {{ altcrit.index.1 }}
    {%for field in form %}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}

</form>
```

Im expecting the `{{ altcrit.index.1 }}` to properly show the second variable of the list in the position 'index' of the outer list .
Instead nothing shows up .
But when I replace the 'index' in `{{ altcrit.index.1 }}` with 1 the expected value of the list of lists shows up .
Meaning : `{{ altcrit.1.1 }}`

Show the question is why is this happening ?

Comment: Because lookups are always literals

Comment: So how can I have the expected result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to get the expected result BY writing a custom tag.

Tag:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def lol_content(*args, **kwargs):
    outer_index = kwargs['outer_index']
    inner_index = kwargs['inner_index']
    list_of_lists = kwargs['list_of_lists']
    return list_of_lists[outer_index][inner_index]
```